# CSS: Center element on x and y

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say that I have a div in an html document with an absolute position, like so:

```
<div style="position:absolute">Hello!</div>
```

Now let's say I want to give it an X and a Y (likely through JQuery, for my purposes).  This is easy enough, just set the "left" and "top" properties to X and Y respectively.  
This task, however, gets a great deal harder when the X and Y are to be the center of this div.  If the size of the div is not always guaranteed to be the same, you can't just offset the X and Y to the approprate amount. 
 If it is possible, how does one set the center of a div to a specific X and Y?  In case it helps, these divs will only ever contain text, no sub elements. 
 
I would prefer to use CSS rather than JavaScript, but if that is necessary, I'd be okay with it.

Comment: Is requirement to center `div` in viewport ?

Comment: Well you could always find the center coordinates by calculating: `childDiv.left = parentDiv.width / 2 - childDiv.width / 2` and `childDiv.top = parentDiv.height / 2 - childDiv.height / 2`.

Comment: _“If the size of the div is not always guaranteed to be the same, you can't just offset the X and Y to the approprate amount”_ – why not? If you’re going to use JS anyway, you can simply get the current width and height of the element with it as well, and then do the very simple math. Using a margin-top/-left of (+/-) 50% might also work as a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two ways to center a `div` vertically and horizontally:

**Method 1: Absolute Positioning**

```
#box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* relative to nearest positioned ancestor or body element */
  top: 50%; /*  relative to nearest positioned ancestor or body element */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* relative to element's height & width */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/19pu1g72/

**Method 2: Flexbox**

```
body {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center flex items horizontally, in this case */
    align-items: center; /* center flex items vertically, in this case */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/19pu1g72/1/

Comment: Not sure why you edited the first method, because the translate(-50%, -50%) worked exactly as I wanted.  I think you misunderstood my question, so if necessary I will explain further.  I want Left and Top to be variable, not necessarily 50%.  If you edit your answer to reflect this, I'll accept it.

Comment: I didn't change the code. Just added comments with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `calc()` , setting `left` to `50% - /* element width */ / 2` , `top` to `50% - /* element height */ / 2`

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:24px;
  top:calc(50% - 24px / 2);
  left:calc(50% - 100px / 2);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Also mention the support for `calc()`

Comment: This is a legit solution, if you know the exact size of the div.  The issue is that I don't necessarily know the exact size of the div, so a different method is necessary.  The accepted answer used `translate(-50%, -50%)`, which worked as I wanted